# Группирование значений таблицы MySQL при выводе

Tags: php, mysqli

Здравствуйте.
Есть две таблицы - таблица продуктов и таблица заказов, связанные через id продукта. Мне нужно вывести данные из этих таблиц так, чтобы мне писалось на экране:

```
Заказ № 1:
список продуктов
Заказ № 2:
список продуктов
```

И так далее. В данный момент я добился того, что у меня выводит список:

```
Заказ № 1
продукт
Заказ № 1
продукт
Заказ № 2
продукт
```

Запрос к БД в данный момент

```
SELECT orders.id, menu.dish_name
FROM orders, menu
WHERE orders.dish_id = menu.id
ORDER BY orders.id
```

1. Нужно ли что-то менять в запросе?
2. Возможно, нужно как-то действовать через array_unique или подобные команды?

Спасибо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37107/discussion-on-question-by-tehebuk----mysql--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо [splash58](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180637/splash58) и [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) за решение!

Структуру базы можно просмотреть - [здесь](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/355d3/2).

Окончательный код:

```
SELECT orders.id, group_concat(menu.dish_name SEPARATOR '<br>') AS dish_name
FROM orders
JOIN menu ON dish_id = menu.id
GROUP BY orders.id
ORDER BY orders.id
```

Если нужен разделитель запятая, можете убрать `SEPARATOR '<br>'` (запятая стоит по default-у), или ставить свой разделитель.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку решение с group_concat() является заведомо ущербным, и когда в реальности надо будет вывести не только название ингредиента, а также его количество или ид для ссылки, то выяснится что оно не подходит,

А также поскольку каждый пионер в любом случае должен использовать PDO вместо mysqli

```
$sql = 'SELECT orders.id, menu.dish_name
            FROM orders, menu
            WHERE orders.dish_id = menu.id
            ORDER BY orders.id';
$data = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

Comment: Уважаемый, прекратите умничать. Я не боюсь новых понятий и я прекрасно осведомлён о PDO. Но мне НУЖНО по условиям ЗАДАЧИ использовать MySQLi. Повторяю ещё раз, если вдруг не дошло - НУЖНО MySQLi.

Comment: Уважаемый, этот сайт - не твоя персональная служба поддержки. Предполагается, что ответ на вопрос будет полезен всем, у кого возникнет подобная проблема. Возможно, среди них найдутся не столь капризные экземпляры.

Comment: Это тоже верно. :)

Comment: вот только не нужно тыкать, я с Вами на брудершафт не пил.